# editing text between two lines of text in a file with bash

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to edit a group of values between to tags using a bash script. I will be using this same code for a few other values through the script.

My Code so far:

```
function preforkeditor {
    httpedit=$1
    read -e -p "What is our new Start Servers? " -i 8 ifmodfork_StartServers
    read -e -p "What is our new Min Spare Server? " -i 5 ifmodfork_MinSpareServer
    read -e -p "What is our new Max Spare Server? " -i 20 ifmodfork_MaxSpareServers
    read -e -p "What is our new Server Limit? " -i 256 ifmodfork_ServerLimit
    read -e -p "What is our new Max Clients? " -i 256 ifmodfork_MaxClients
    read -e -p "What is our new Max Request Per Child? " -i 4000    ifmodfork_MaxRequestsPerChild
    sed -n '/<IfModule prefork*/,/<\/IfModule>/p' $httpdedit
}
```

This pulls the information I am looking for, but I don't know how to edit the information.

I also tried to use a few lines of codes I found online, but the search does not work.

```
sed -i "/^<IfModule prefork*/,/^IfModule>/{
    /StartServers/ s/${startserver} */9/
    /MinSpareServer/ s/${MinSpareServers} */3/
    /MaxSpareServers/ s/${MaxSpareServers} */21/
    /ServerLimit/ s/${ServerLimit} */300/
    /MaxClients/ s/${MaxClients} */300/
    /MaxRequestsPerChild/ s/${MaxRequestsPerChild} */5000/
}" httpd.test
```

below is the information i am trying to edit.

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
    StartServers       8
    MinSpareServers    5
    MaxSpareServers   20
    ServerLimit      256
    MaxClients       256
    MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>
```

If you know of a simpler way, let me know. My goal is to change to change the numbers. The same values are else where in the file I am trying to edit.

Comment: What is the desired output? Just to change the numbers?

Comment: Yep, I'm trying to change the numbers around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a slight modification to your own suggestion will work:

```
sed  "/^<IfModule prefork*/,/^<\/IfModule>/ {
    /StartServers/        s/[0-9][0-9]*/9/
    /MinSpareServer/      s/[0-9][0-9]*/3/
    /MaxSpareServers/     s/[0-9][0-9]*/21/
    /ServerLimit/         s/[0-9][0-9]*/300/
    /MaxClients/          s/[0-9][0-9]*/300/
    /MaxRequestsPerChild/ s/[0-9][0-9]*/5000/
}" httpd.test
```

If you have a recent `sed`, you can replace `[0-9][0-9]*` with `[0-9]\+`. If any of your keywords has a digit, you will need to add angle brackets, `\<[0-9][0-9]*\>`.

Other changes:

- Fixed error:`/^IfModule>/` to `/^<\/IfModule>/`
- `/^<IfModule prefork/` doesn't need a `*`

Also, you presumably will want the change the first substitution, for example, to:

```
    /StartServers/        s/[0-9][0-9]*/$ifmodfork_StartServers/
```

to use the user's input.

Comment: Thank you. This works like a charm. I know the numbers helps, but was the spacing the issue as well?

Comment: @David: What you had, `s/${startserver} */9/`, doesn't seem to make sense. But `s/${startserver}/9/` would change `8` to `9`, it `$startserver` were `8`.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following into a file called `Foo.sed`. **Add lines as appropriate for the rest of your changes.**

It will perform the substitutions inside the curly braces only inside blocks that start with a line containing `<IfModule prefork.c>` and ending with a line containing `</IfModule>`. The `\1` is a back-reference to the previously matched expression.

```
/<IfModule prefork.c>/,/<\/IfModule>/ {
s/\(StartServers\s\+\)[0-9]\+/\1 11/
s/\(MinSpareServers\s\+\)[0-9]\+/\1 12312321/
}
```

And run it like this:

```
sed -f Foo.sed Input.txt
```

It will print the transformed version to standard out.
If you are satisfied with the output, you can then do the in-place change

```
sed -i -f Foo.sed Input.txt
```